# HTML file input with possibility to input several files one after another

Tags: javascript, html, file, input

I'm looking for a possibility to input several files in a row in an HTML form. It strikes me that there seems to be no easy solution for this (or at least I haven't been able to find it despite several hours of searching). If I use the `multiple` attribute in an `<input type="file" name="myFiles[]" multiple />`, I can choose several files at a time holding Ctrl, but if I choose one file at first, then click the input field again and choose another one, the second file seems to overwrite the first one. 
So I thought I might try to use javascript to add more `<input type="file" name="myFiles[]" />` fields (with the same name), since I have seen something similar somewhere. I tried the following:
JavaScript:

```
function addInputFileEle() {
    var field = document.getElementById("filesField");
    var row = '<input type="file" name="myFiles[]" onchange="addInputFileEle();" />';
    field.innerHTML += row; // add one more <input type="file" .../> element
}
```

HTML:

```
<form method="post" action="#" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <fieldset id="filesField"> <!--for adding more file-input rows-->
         <input type="file" multiple name="myFiles[]" class="multi" onchange="addInputFileEle();" />
     </fieldset>
     <input type="submit"/>
 </form>
```

The document indeed does create additional file-input elements whenever I click on one of them and select a file, BUT: The file does not get uploaded! I mean, after I select the file, the file name does not get displayed, instead, it still says "Choose a file" (or "Select a file", not sure about English). So apparently my `onchange="addInputFileEle()"` overwrites the normal reaction (the file getting 'loaded' into the input element)? Even though this does not seem logical to me. Can anyone help? Why does the file not get selected in the end? Or maybe there is a simpler solution than mine, which would of course be very welcome. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Looking at that, it rerenders the fieldset, therefore clearing the value.

Comment: @CodingWithClass Oh yes, you're right... that was fast, thanks! Do you know any standard solution for this several-file-uploads though?

Comment: you can use appendChild instead of innerHTML. I made a fiddle with an equal solution: http://jsfiddle.net/tfrqwre9/

Comment: Try to see your console if it logs anything @PeterMöhrenbart

Comment: @JoshuaK I used appendChild as you suggested and it works now, many thanks!! Somehow I could not make the code work you posted on fiddle, no new input elements were showing up there (not 100% sure if I used it the way you meant though)

Comment: they are hidden ;) click send and take a look at the network tab of your debugging sytsem (like firebug)

Comment: @JoshuaK the $_FILES variable (using PHP) always contains only the latest-uploaded file, shouldn't the files be there?

Comment: @PeterMöhrenbart tested it. works like a charm! check out my test file: http://pastebin.com/st0trMM9 (ah pls change `nI.multiple = '';` to `nI.multiple = 'multiple';`if you are not doing this, you can only select one file per open dialog)

Comment: if you think the user will be confused because they don't see the selection. add a little piece of code, that shows the filenames and / or a preview of the files. very easy with the javascript `File API` and canvas. there are many examples on the internet

Comment: @JoshuaK oh right... indeed I misunderstood how I should have embedded your code~ Thanks very much for your help! I will meditate over your code sample and learn from it

Answer (score 0):

Ok I will just post my solution in case anyone else is searching for a way to select several files for upload one by one. As @CodingWithClass pointed out, I was resetting the input field by using something like `parentElement.innerHTML += additionalInputElement;`. Instead, I should have used appendChild as @JoshuaK suggested:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <script>
            function addFileInput(fieldsetName, firstInputId) {
                var fs = document.getElementById(fieldsetName);
                // only add one if the last file-input field is not empty
                if(fs.lastElementChild.value != '') {
                    var firstInputFile = document.getElementById(firstInputId);
                    var newInputFile = document.createElement("input");
                    newInputFile.type = firstInputFile.type;
                    newInputFile.name=firstInputFile.name;
                    newInputFile.multiple=firstInputFile.multiple;
                    newInputFile.class = firstInputFile.class;
                    newInputFile.onchange=firstInputFile.onchange;
                    fs.appendChild(newInputFile);
                }
            }
        </script>
        <title>MultiFile-Testing</title>
    </head>
    <body>

<?php print_r($_FILES); // see if files were uploaded in the previous round ?> 

        <form method="post" action="#" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <fieldset id="filesFS">
                <input type="file" multiple name="myFiles[] id="firstInputFile" onchange="addFileInput('filesFS', 'firstInputFile');" />
            </fieldset>
            <input type="submit"/>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```